# Enumerate string elements of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of strings, for example

```
users = ["anka", "anka", "anka", "anka", "timothy", "timothy", "timothy", "donald", "donald", "anka", "anka", "timothy", "timothy"]
```

I would like now to efficiently turn this list into a list of integers by enumerating the strings. The output is

```
users = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

How is this possible?

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Comment: You have not even sent a code. This leads us to believe that you are merely looking for someone else to solve your work. (Try using a dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to prepare a dictionary with the user and the count of distinct users so far as the key-value pair respectively and generate the required list while using the dictionary:

```
users = ["anka", "anka", "anka", "anka", "timothy", "timothy", "timothy", "donald", "donald", "anka", "anka", "timothy", "timothy"]
idx = {}
result = []
for user in users:
    if user not in idx.keys():
        idx[user] = len(idx.keys())
    result.append(idx[user])
print(result)
```

Comment: You can get rid of ```enumerate``` and directly use ```for user in users:``` should be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You could use set to get the unique names then a list comprehension to get the index of each name in the original list.

```python
users = ["anka", "anka", "anka", "anka", "timothy", "timothy", "timothy", "donald", "donald", "anka", "anka", "timothy", "timothy"]

positions = [list(set(users)).index(user) for user in users]

print(positions)
```